# How can I join these MYSQL tables?

Tags: mysql

I'm having 2 tables. Table A contains a list of people who booked for an event, table B has a list of people the booker from table A brings with him/her. Both tables have many colums with unique data that I need to do certain calculations on in PHP , and as of now I do so by doing queries on the tables with a recursive PHP function to resolve it. I want to simplify the PHP and reduce the amount of queries that come from this recursive function by doing better MYSQL queries but I'm kind of stuck.

Because the table has way to many columns I will give an Excerpt of table A instead:

```
booking_id | A_customer | A_insurance
1          | 134        | 4
```

Excerpt of table B:

```
id | booking_id | B_insurance
1  | 1          | 0
2  | 1          | 1
3  | 1          | 1
4  | 1          | 3
```

The booking_id in table A is unique and set to auto increment, the booking_id in table b can occur many times (depending on how many guests the client from table A brings with him). Lets say I want to know every selected insurance from customer 134 and his guests, then I want the output like this:

```
booking_id | insurance
1          | 4
1          | 0
1          | 1
1          | 1
1          | 3
```

I have tried a couple of joins and this is the closest I've came yet, unfortunately this fails to show the row from A and only shows the matching rows in B.

```
SELECT a.booking_id,a.A_customer,a.A_insurance,b.booking_id,b.insurance FROM b INNER JOIN a ON (b.booking_id = a.booking_id) WHERE a.booking_id = 134
```

Can someone point me into the right direction ?

Please note: I have altered the table and column names for stackoverflow so it's easy for you guys to read, so it's possible that there is a typo that would break the query in it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a `union all` for this:

```
select a.booking_id, a.insurance
from a
where a.a_customer = 134
union all
select b.booking_id, b.insurance
from a join
     b
     on a.booking_id = b.booking_id
where a.a_customer = 134;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of to achieve this is to use a UNION:

```
SELECT booking_id, A_insurance insurance
FROM A
WHERE booking_id = 134

UNION

SELECT booking_id, B_insurance insurance
FROM B
WHERE booking_id = 134
```

Comment: It is, except for that I apperently needed UNION ALL to get the duplicate records on my primary key !

Answer (score 1):

As my understanging of your isso is right, that should give you the result you need:

```
 SELECT a.booking_id,a.insurance FROM a WHERE a.booking_id = 134
union
 SELECT a.booking_id,b.insurance FROM b INNER JOIN a ON (b.booking_id = a.booking_id) WHERE a.booking_id = 134
```